# Using 1 variable for more values

Tags: java, object, instance

pretty new to this stuff and am struggling with this problem... I am supposed to create a variable that has many instances. For example in my case I need to ask the user for city of departure and city of arrival.

```
    System.out.println("Vnesite ime mesta kamor potujete: "); // here is where i ask for the first city 
    String mesto = scan.next();
    System.out.println("Vnesite ime države kamor potujete: ");
    String drzava = scan.next();
    System.out.println("Vnesite ime mesta iz katerega potujete: "); //here is where i ask for the second city
    String mesto2 = scan.next();
    System.out.println("Vnesite ime države iz katere potujete: ");
    String drzava2 = scan.next();


    Kraj kraj = new Kraj(mesto, drzava);
```

and here is where the instances of the variable should be stored.

```
public class Kraj {

private String kraj;  // this variable is supposed to have many instances
private String drzava;

public Kraj(String kraj, String drzava)
{
    this.kraj = kraj; 
    this.drzava = drzava;
}

public String getkraj ( )
{
    return kraj; 
}

public void setkraj (String kraj)
{ 
    this.kraj = kraj; 
}

public String getdrzava ( )
{
    return drzava; 
}

public void setdrzava (String drzava)
{
    this.drzava = drzava; 
}
```

I've tried creating the second variable, but it doesn't solve anything (what if the traveler wants to make a stop at a destination in the middle and then proceed to the final destination). Im looking for explanation if possible not the solution :)

thanks in advance guys/girls!

Comment: Either store a List of `kraj` Objects, or store a List of `String` kraj and drzavas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have **a List of `String` to store multiple destinations** as shown below:

```
public class Kraj {

   private List<String> kraj;//now stores multiple destinations

   public List<String> getkraj() {
     return kraj; 
   }

   public void setkraj(List<String> kraj) { 
      this.kraj = kraj; 
   }

   //add drzava and it's setters and getters

}
```

So, in your main code, you need to collect them to an array and pass as shown below:

```
List<String> destinations = new ArrayList<>();
System.out.println("Vnesite ime mesta kamor potujete: ");
    String mesto = scan.next();
    System.out.println("Vnesite ime države kamor potujete: ");
    String drzava = scan.next();
    destinations.add(drzava);
    System.out.println("Vnesite ime mesta iz katerega potujete: ");
    String mesto2 = scan.next();
    System.out.println("Vnesite ime države iz katere potujete: ");
    String drzava2 = scan.next();
    destinations.add(drzava2);

    Kraj kraj = new Kraj(mesto, destinations);
```

Comment: I recommend to use a List instead of array, so we can add as much as items they want.

Comment: Yes, you are right `List` makes more scense, thank you

Comment: Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

here you store 1st two variables.

```
Kraj kraj = new Kraj(mesto, drzava);
```

then you can create another object of your class and store remaining two variables.like this.

```
Kraj kraj2 = new Kraj(mesto2, drzava2);
```

Comment: I've tried something similar but if im getting this right this will only let u store another 2 variables. What if the user wants to store 10 variables? Or am i mistaken?

Comment: your class is only design to take two variables for 10 variables you can create Array of objects and store like in above answer.